# How to filter custom content type nodes using ajax in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-views, drupal-search

I'm in a situation where I think I need to create my own custom search module. What I'm trying to do is make a page with a list of all my nodes in the node type - let's call it 'Beer'. So I want to be able to filter through the beers in a fashion similar to the one you find on the Apple Trailers page ( http://trailers.apple.com/ ).

I tried using Views 2 but ran it to a few problems:

- I can't make the filter links like in the top of the trailers page (exclusive, just HD etc.)
- The search function will only search one field (Exposed field "Beer title" but I also want it to search for manufacturer and other things.

I'm aware of a couple of solutions:

- I could fix the last problem by using the Computed Field Module where I could combine the fields I want to search through. I just don't see this as a very elegant solution.
- I could make my own module and create my own database queries where I apply the relevant filters (I just don't know how).
- I could somehow use my already installed Solr module.

So the first solution - the easiest I guess but also kind of bad with duplicate content in my database.

The second solution - the best (maybe) - problem: I'm too dumb.

The third solution - Solr seems pretty cool but would I be able to present my beer nodes with just the title and a picture?

So I guess my question is. Which one of the three would you use? Or what other solutions could I potentially use (I'm confident there are things I haven't thought of :))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this could be a good use for Taxonomy not different node types. Also, Have you considered http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs ?

You could set up each "filter" as a tab that passes an argument down to a view. Then don't expose any views filters to the user.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could use Taxonomy in this situation. I need the different fields in my content type. And I'd like to be able to search in each of these custom fields with only one search field.

But the filter things with the links that passes an argument to a view sounds like the right solution for creating "filter links". Is Quicktabs the best solution for this?

Comment: I decided to go with the Computed Field Module anyway. Thanks for your answer.